# styling tagstyles <ol> doesnt work on RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html'

Tags: html, react-native, react-native-render-html

i want to change font color and line height on numbering list  on RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html' but it doesnt work. this is my code

```
`<RenderHtml
                html={caraPakai}
                imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width - 30}
                allowFontScaling={false}
                ignoredStyles={[
                  'font-weight',
                  'color',
                  'font-family',
                  'font-size',
                  'background-color'
                ]}
                tagsStyles={{
                  li: { color: '#707E8D' },
                  ol: {
                    color: '#707E8D',
                    lineHeight: 22
                  },
                }}`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnfff.png)

styling ol on tagStyles doesnt work

styling ol on tagStyles